# OpenPop doesn't delete messeages since 30.06.2021

Tags: openpop

since one Day, openpop deletes no message in office365/Exchange online.
I use

pop.DeleteMessage(i) 'Delete message

The Message is marked to delete and i check this with a new

pop.GetMessageCount

The counter is one lower then before.

At the end of all transactions i  use

If pop.Connected Then pop.Disconnect()
pop.Dispose()

Is there anyone with the similar problem and a solution?
Kind regards
Hendrik

Comment: Sorry, the "Hello" is missing...Sorry

Comment: THe capacity of the Dustbin of the Mailbox is exeeded, so it can't delete,